# getting environment variables from remote machine is very slow

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I'm using the following code in order to retrieve environment variables from remote machine

the problem is, it takes very long for the code to run.

```
    DataTable envVarliables = new DataTable();
            envVarliables.Columns.Add("UserName");
            envVarliables.Columns.Add("VarName");
            envVarliables.Columns.Add("VarValue");

            ManagementObjectSearcher query = null;
            ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = null;

            ConnectionOptions opt = new ConnectionOptions();

            opt.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
            opt.EnablePrivileges = true;

            opt.Username = @"domain\user";
            opt.Password = @"password";
            try
            {
                ManagementPath p = new ManagementPath(@"\\servername" + "\\root\\cimv2");

                ManagementScope msc = new ManagementScope(p, opt);

                SelectQuery q = new SelectQuery("select * from Win32_Environment where Name='IBMSENV' ");

                query = new ManagementObjectSearcher(msc, q, null);
                queryCollection = query.Get();

                //Console.WriteLine(queryCollection.Count);
                List<string> temp = new List<string>();

                  foreach (ManagementBaseObject envVar in queryCollection)
                    {
                        if (envVar["Name"].ToString() == "MYENVVARNAME")
                        {
                            envVarliables.Rows.Add(envVar["UserName"].ToString(), envVar["Name"].ToString(),
                            envVar["VariableValue"].ToString());
                        }
envVar["VariableValue"].ToString());
                        //temp.Add(envVar["Name"].ToString());
                    }
                return envVarliables;
```

My problem is in the line `foreach (ManagementBaseObject envVar in queryCollection)`
which takes around 30 seconds to 1.5 minutes or even more to execute on the first time it reaches that line.

After that it cycle very fast.

Question is, can I enhance something to make it work faster?

Another question, is there another way to get the data from remote machine?
For example to get other data from remote machine I used
https://code.google.com/p/cassia/ but it doesn't have methods to retrieve the environment variables

Comment: I've seen this before, or something very similar.  Try enabling the "Remote Service Management (RPC)" exception in the firewall on the remote machine.

Comment: will ask IT to do it, thanks

Comment: @HarryJohnston - Hi, tried what you suggested but it didn't help :(

Comment: Could be a different port, I guess.  Try using `netstat` during the initial delay to see whether the client is trying to connect and being blocked by the firewall; look for a state of SYN_SENT.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I'm not sure it's a port issue.
The query it self is executed on remote machine on this line
"queryCollection = query.Get();"
That line execute in less than a second.
The first time it tries to run the members in this line "foreach (ManagementBaseObject envVar in queryCollection)" is what takes 30 secs or more

Comment: That's not necessarily true, the query may be being lazy-evaluated, i.e., it doesn't bother to connect to the remote machine until you actually ask for the first result.  It's easy to tell - if, during the delay, `netstat` shows that the connection is ESTABLISHED or TIME_WAIT, then there isn't an issue establishing the connection; if it says SYN_SENT, then there is.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Hi, i checked it and it says TIME_WAIT, so I guess it's not a connection issue